# PostgreSQL and extension tablefunc with enumerated type

Tags: postgresql, sql, grouping, cross-tabulation

In PostgreSQL,

I created an enumerated type

```
CREATE TYPE w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad
as ENUM ('transféré', 'traité', 'non soumis', 'ouvert', 'non traité','PAC réalisé');
```

then a table

```
CREATE TABLE w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement
(id_sign INT PRIMARY KEY,  
annee_signal integer,
...
etat w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad,
geom geometry(point,2154));
```

I want to obtain a double entry table counting the number of folders according to the value of the type using the postgres TableFunc extension.

Example of using the TableFunc extension

```
*CREATE TABLE w_bpms.test (Section CHAR(1), Status VARCHAR(10), count integer);

INSERT INTO w_bpms.test VALUES ('A', 'Active',   1);
INSERT INTO w_bpms.test VALUES ('A', 'Inactive', 2);
INSERT INTO w_bpms.test VALUES ('B', 'Active',   4);
INSERT INTO w_bpms.test VALUES ('B', 'Inactive', 5);
INSERT INTO w_bpms.test VALUES ('C', 'Inactive', 7);  
 

SELECT * from w_bpms.test

SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT section, status, count
    FROM    w_bpms.test
    ORDER  BY 1,2'  -- could also just be "ORDER BY 1" here
  , $$VALUES ('Active'::text), ('Inactive')$$
   ) AS ct ("Section" text, "Active" int, "Inactive" int);*
```

Is it possible to use this extension with an enumerated type?

Below is my query which does not work

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
'SELECT annee_signal, count(*) AS NB, 
    count (case when etat = 'transféré'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end),
    count (case when etat = 'traité'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end), 
    count (case when etat = 'non soumis'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end),
    count (case when etat = 'ouvert'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end), 
    count (case when etat = 'non traité'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end),
    count (case when etat = 'PAC réalisé'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad then 1 end)
FROM  w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement 
ORDER BY 1,2'  -- could also just be "ORDER BY 1" here
    , $$VALUES 
    ('transféré'::text),
    ('traité'::text),
    ('non soumis'::text),
    ('ouvert'::text),
    ('non traité'::text),
    ('PAC réalisé'::text)
    $$ ) 
    AS ct ("annee signal" text, 
        "transféré" int,
        "traité" int,
        "non soumis" int,
        "ouvert" int,           
        "non traité" int,
        "PAC réalisé" int);

ERROR: syntax error at or near "transféré" LINE 4: count (case when etat = 'transféré'::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_s... ^ État SQL : 42601 Caractère : 116
```

Comment: I don't know how to duplicate this question in another forum and above all this question is useful to Qgis form users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would *quite* literally do the same as in the example you provided - PG elegantly handles what you might think complicated with `ENUM` types:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CROSSTAB(
    -- I assume you want a GROUP BY count here
    $$
    SELECT
      annee_signal, etat,
      COUNT(*)::INT
    FROM
      w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement
    GROUP BY
      1, 2
    ORDER BY
      1, 2
    $$,
    -- get a list of your ENUM values via ENUM_RANGE system function
    $$
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      UNNEST(
        ENUM_RANGE(NULL::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad)
      )
    $$
  ) AS ct (
    annee_signal  INT,
    "transféré"   INT,
    "traité"      INT,
    "non soumis"  INT,
    "ouvert"      INT,           
    "non traité"  INT,
    "PAC réalisé" INT
  )
;
```

*Note the `$$` string literal escaping - this is terribly wrong in your query, where you are incorrectly wrapping your SQL string literal in too few `'`; PG complains about this very issue, although your query logic would result in plenty others...*

---

Now, if this is something you wanted to run over and over you may find it useful to wrap this into your own `CROSSTAB` extension:

- write up the desired return type:

  ```
  CREATE TYPE w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_type AS (
    "Anne Signal" INT,
    "Transféré"   INT,
    "Traité"      INT,
    "Non Soumis"  INT,
    "Ouvert"      INT,           
    "Non Traité"  INT,
    "PAC Réalisé" INT
  );
  ```
- write a *specific* `CROSSTAB` wrapper:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_func (
    table_sql    TEXT,
    category_sql TEXT
  ) RETURNS SETOF w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_type
      LANGUAGE C
      '$libdir/tablefunc','crosstab_hash'
      STABLE
      STRICT
  ;
  ```

which you can then run like

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_func(
    $$
    SELECT
      annee_signal, etat,
      COUNT(*)::INT
    FROM
      w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement
    GROUP BY
      1, 2
    ORDER BY
      1, 2
    $$,
    $$
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      UNNEST(
        ENUM_RANGE(NULL::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad)
      )
    $$
  )
;
```

---

**Bonus:**

Let's get ourselves ultimate convenience: use your standard SQL string literal as `DEFAULT` for the `CROSSTAB` wrapper function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_func (
   table_sql    TEXT DEFAULT $$SELECT annee_signal, etat, COUNT(*)::INT FROM w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2$$,
   category_sql TEXT DEFAULT $$SELECT UNNEST(ENUM_RANGE(NULL::w_sebio.t_sebio_type_sad))$$
 ) RETURNS SETOF w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_type
     LANGUAGE C
     '$libdir/tablefunc','crosstab_hash'
     STABLE
     STRICT
 ;
```

and simply run

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  w_sebio.t_sebio_signalement__pivot_func()
;
```

Comment: @ Géozélot  THANKS. It works perfectly well. For functions,
for my part I replaced: AS LANGUAGE C '$libdir/tablefunc', 'crosstab_hash' STABLE STRICT by
AS '$libdir/tablefunc','crosstab_hash' LANGUAGE C STABLE STRICT

One last question, can we also retrieve the total number per year?

Comment: @fcka ah thx., the `AS` in the function definitions were just typos -> corrected. The base values that get passed into the `CROSSTAB` functions are defined by the `table_sql` query, so if you want numbers by year, just `GROUP BY` accordingly and add the `"Year"` column to the `CROSSTAB` input and result types.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I have nothing to do with it. I was criticized for not asking this question in the right forum ("This question is off-topic. At this time he is not accepting responses."). I indicated that I do not have the rights to transfer the question and answer to another forum, but I did not get a response.